# How to use contains function in json xpath using java

Tags: json, xpath, jsonpath

```
{
            "store": {
                "book": [ {
                    "category": "reference",
                    "author": "Nigel Rees",
                    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                    "price": 8.95
                }, {
                    "category": "fiction",
                    "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                    "title": "Sword of Honour",
                    "price": 12.99
                }, {
                    "category": "fiction",
                    "author": "Herman Melville",
                    "title": "Moby Dick",
                    "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                    "price": 8.99
                }, {
                    "category": "fiction",
                    "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                    "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                    "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                    "price": 22.99
                } ],
                "bicycle": [ {
                    "color": "red",
                    "price": 19.95,
                    "style": [ "city", "hybrid" ]
                }, {
                    "color": "blue",enter code here
                    "price": 59.91,
                    "style": [ "downhill", "freeride" ]
                } ]
            }
        }
```

How to fetch the title of book having author name contains 'Rees' using json path, I have tried using "$.book.[?(@.author =~ /.*'Rees')]" but its not working for me, can anyone please help me.